# Porting iOS Spritekit to Android, what is animateWithTexture equivalent?

Tags: sprite-kit, cocos2d-android

I've created a new Cocos2d project for Android to try and port across my iOS Spritekit 2D Game to Android and can't seem to figure out how to animate in Android for Cocos2D?

My code in iOS I want to port is as follows:

```
SKTexture* crowTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"crow1"];
SKTexture* crowTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"crow2"];

SKAction* flap = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[crowTexture1,crowTexture2] timePerFrame:0.5]];

[crow runAction:flap];
```

My cocos2d java code is as follows, so far:

```
        CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
    CCSprite player = CCSprite.sprite("crow1.png");

    player.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(player.getContentSize().width / 2.0f, winSize.height / 2.0f));

    addChild(player);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are two cocos2d-android(-1) forks, which one are you using? Are you really using these java-based engines and not cocos2d-x? (asking because users often tag incorrectly) Have you tried apportable to port (cross-compile) your Objc app directly?

Comment: Hi, I'm using cocos2d (java) not cocos2d-x (C++). I haven't looked too much into apportable, but I thought that wouldn't be able to port iOS Spritekit to Android?

Comment: you can use apportable if your game doesn't use physics

Comment: Oh ok, unfortunately my game does use physics. My game is a simple 2D game like Flappy Bird which I want to port across to Android.